# Limit of a sequence of functions $f_n$ defined implicitly from the sequence of functions $F_n$ by the Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I have a sequence of functions $f_n(x,y)$ where each $f_n$ is defined by the Implicit Function Theorem from a particular $C^1$ function $F_n(x,y,z)$, that is, $F_n(x,y,f_n(x,y))=0$. The sequence $F_n$ is converging pointwise to the function $F$ which is also $C^1$. I wonder if we can conclude that $f_n$ converges pointwise to the function $f$ defined implicitly from $F$ by the Implicit Function Theorem? I haven't been able to find such a result. Thank you for any insight.